# CKEditor Widget highlighted contents

Tags: ckeditor

I have two questions regarding CKEditor Widgets:

First of all - I want to make it so when I highlight text and then click the widget's toolbar button, the highlighted contents are inserted into one of the widget's editable areas. How do I do that?

Secondly, I need to be able to nest my widgets - so in one of the widget's editable areas, I need to be able to add more instances of the widget. Currently, when inside my widget, the button for my widget is disabled. I tried adding allowedContent: true in the definition, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second question – support for nesting widget is introduced in CKEditor 4.5.0 which will be released next week. See [4.5.0 Beta blog post](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.5-Beta-Released). Before CKEditor 4.5.0 there's no support for nesting widgets, hence the button is disabled.